# toggle select lists using jQuery closest or next?

Tags: jquery, css

There are 3 select boxes like below. I want to be able to use jQuery toggle to display the select list items and hide the select list items. Is it possible using jQuery.closest() or jQuery.next()?

```
<dt><a href="#"><span>A - All</span></a></dt>            

        <dd>
        <ul>                          
            <li><a href="#">A<img class="flag"/><span class="value">A</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B<img class="flag"/><span class="value">B</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C<img class="flag"/><span class="value">C</span></a></li>
        </ul>                                                        
        </dd>

    </dl>


    <dt><a href="#"><span>A1 - All</span></a></dt>            

            <dd>
            <ul>                          
                <li><a href="#">A1<img class="flag"/><span class="value">A1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B1<img class="flag"/><span class="value">B1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C1<img class="flag"/><span class="value">C1</span></a></li>
            </ul>                                                        
            </dd>

    </dl>

        <dt><a href="#"><span>A2 - All</span></a></dt>            

                <dd>
                <ul>                          
                    <li><a href="#">A2<img class="flag"/><span class="value">A2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B2<img class="flag"/><span class="value">B2</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">C2<img class="flag"/><span class="value">C2</span></a></li>
                </ul>                                                        
                </dd>

    </dl>
```

Note: It can be done by adding classes specific to each anchor tag and the following ul tag, but that would be more code. I want to be able to keep it simple with less code!

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want e.g. when the user selects A to hide B1,C1,B2,C2?

Comment: Yes. Clicking on A would open the ul li containing A, B, C only and clicking on it again would hide A, B, C again.

Comment: Also the selected item should populate as the item selected in the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#menu > dd').hide();
            $('#menu dt').click(function () {
                var objNext = $(this).next('dd');
                if (objNext.is(':visible') === true) {
                    objNext.slideUp();
                }
                else {
                    $('#menu > dd').slideUp(); //( when A is clicked A,B,c show . now B is clicked now A1,B1,C1 show and hide A,B,C, ) else ( comment this line alone ).
                    objNext.slideDown();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <dl id="menu">
        <dt><a href="#"><span>A - All</span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">A<img class="flag" /><span class="value">A</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B<img class="flag" /><span class="value">B</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C<img class="flag" /><span class="value">C</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dt><a href="#"><span>A1 - All</span></a> </dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">A1<img class="flag" /><span class="value">A1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B1<img class="flag" /><span class="value">B1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C1<img class="flag" /><span class="value">C1</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
        <dt><a href="#"><span>A2 - All</span></a> </dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">A2<img class="flag" /><span class="value">A2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">B2<img class="flag" /><span class="value">B2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">C2<img class="flag" /><span class="value">C2</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having tidied up your HTML (you seemed to have lots of `</dl>` tags within the list itself, and no opening `<dl>` tag anywhere) to the following:

```
<dl>
    <dt><a href="#"><span>A - All</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A<img class="flag"/><span class="value">A</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B<img class="flag"/><span class="value">B</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C<img class="flag"/><span class="value">C</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
    <dt><a href="#"><span>A1 - All</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A1<img class="flag"/><span class="value">A1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B1<img class="flag"/><span class="value">B1</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C1<img class="flag"/><span class="value">C1</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
    <dt><a href="#"><span>A2 - All</span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">A2<img class="flag"/><span class="value">A2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">B2<img class="flag"/><span class="value">B2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C2<img class="flag"/><span class="value">C2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>​
```

The following jQuery seems to do as you want:

$('dd').hide();

```
$('dt').click(
    function() {
        var that = $(this),
            affect = $(this).nextUntil('dt'),
            v = affect.is(':visible');

        that.closest('dl').find('dd').slideUp(1000);

        if (v == false){
            affect.slideDown(1000);
        }
        else if (v == true) {
            affect.slideUp(1000);
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CZqCt/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/).
- [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).
- [`:visible` selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

Comment: It worked but there was a minor issue. When I have the first dropdown open and try to open another dropdown, the second dropdown values were getting appended to the first one.